# Set quote.shippingAddress() , after adding new billing address in checkout form magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote, shipping-address

Need to Set quote.shippingAddress() , after adding new billing address in checkout form magento 2 in js file.
Actually quote.shippingAddress() gets null after adding new billing address. That's why i need some solution to set it.