# CSS and LESS, what is the correct way for including them in a Magento 2 module?

Tags: magento2, css, less

Let's say I have my module which adds a slider to the homepage and there are many styles to define. I know I can add the styles in 2 different ways:

- Adding a css file MyBrand/MyModule/view/frontend/web/css/myfile.css
- Or adding a less file MyBrand/MyModule/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less

Is there a «more correct» way of adding my file? Should I priorize adding .css instead of .less, is there a specific good practice?

In the [Magento docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html) I don't see any specific guideline regarding this.

Just a note: In my case I wanted to use the function .media-width, so I had to chosse using less.

Answer (score 0):

Using css or less depends upon your requirement ,refer this for more information about this :- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html
https://webkul.com/blog/use-less-magento-2/
https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-quick-guide-create-custom-css-file/

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the file `view/frontend/layout/default.xml` inside your custom module folder.

`Default.xml` is for supplement of JS, CSS or Less files on all pages

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- /** * Copyright © 2015 Scommerce Mage. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
        <link src="MyBrand_MyModule::custom.js"/>
        <css src="MyBrand_MyModule::custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

And very helpful this link refer this :-

**https://magehit.com/blog/inset-jscss-or-less-with-your-custom-module-in-magento-2/**

Any query let me know..

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309714/set-quote-shippingaddress-after-adding-new-billing-address-in-checkout-form

Comment: Thank you for the approach. But it actually doesn't answer my question: should we prioritize including less over css files? Are there any guidelines? Harmendra's answer seems to be a little more explanatory :)

Comment: Please check attached link.